# Dynamically setting docker image tag from semver when using docker-image-resource in concourse

Tags: docker-image, concourse

I have the following `semver` setup:

```
- name: version 
  type: semver
  source:
    driver: gcs
    bucket: my-ci
    json_key: ((my.serviceaccount))
    key: version/version.txt
    initial_version: 0.0.0
```

In my `publish`job, I have the following:

```
 name: publish
  serial_groups: [version]
  plan:
  - get: version
    passed: [build]  
    trigger: true
```

So, basically the publish `job` is triggered after `build` job is passed (version updated)

Now, in the publish job I am creating a docker image and pushing it to `gcr`.

```
  - put: my-gcr
    params:
      additional_tags: my/ci/tags
      build: mycode
    get_params: {skip_download: true}
```

Here, the image is correctly tagged based on the values in the `tags` file. However, I want to set these values dynamically based on the current version which can be retreived following this:

https://concoursetutorial.com/miscellaneous/versions-and-buildnumbers/#display-version

How can I use this version number to tag my docker image?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using the following code:

```
- put: artifacts
    params:
      additional_tags: version/number
      build: mycode
    get_params: {skip_download: true}
```